# Drupal, recognize if a visitor likes or not a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, drupal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect Facebook page fan on the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070465/detect-facebook-page-fan-on-the-website)

I have a question to do, can there be a way for a drupal website to recognize if the visitor likes or not a facebook page, without authentication, just by a simple visit?

Thanks..

Comment: short answer... **NOT POSSIBLE**

Comment: Thanks, i thought so, but can you please explain me in professional terms why not? I have to convince someone about this but i don't know how to do it!

Comment: Why not: Because that information is not accessible from outside Facebook _without_ authentication – for an obvious reason called _privacy_. („Inside” Facebook, meaning on an app page tab on a fan site, that info can be read from the signed_request parameter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already answered as comments but here is why.

If the user hasn't authenticated with a facebook app you coded, you can not access user information using a server-side script. You can however imaging to use an iframe'd like button and to use Javascript to check the iframe content. It doesn't work either.

Javascripts has a policy that is doesn't work through DOMs over different domains. 
See http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php#access

I see another question here which is already closed and I'm not wondering if this happens to this question as well.